# How to call void method on a GUI button?

Tags: java

I really need a help with how to call this void method on my button. The point is that the method has to be void according to the requirement. I have the method and the button on which I'm trying to call the method

```
public static void printIntBinary(int x) {
    if (x <= 0) {
    } else {
        // System.out.println(x % 2)
        printIntBinary(x / 2);
        System.out.println(x % 2);
    }
}

//Portion of my Gui.. runButton actionListner
runButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        try{
            int mm = Integer.parseInt(binaryTextField.getText());
            //I'm having problem down here.. Because my method printInBinary is void type
            binaryOutPut.append(Recurs.printIntBinary(mm));
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ertyui");
        }
```

Comment: The method `binaryOutPut.append(...)` takes a parameter, and you're calling your method `Recurs.printIntbinary(mm)` which returns nothing, so you're putting in `void` as a parameter, which doesn't work.

Comment: What do you suggest please?

Comment: Don't use `MouseListener` with buttons, use an `ActionListener`, see [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: I think you want to change `public static void printIntBinary(int x) {` to `public static int printIntBinary(int x) {` and then return the result of the calculation (`x % 2`) from the method...or create a new method which does this...

Comment: Please MouseListener is not my problem on this case. The problem is to make the method call right. Thank you!

Comment: Well I think the same  changing it to static int and return the result. But my assignment requirement stated that it has to be void type.. so bad!

Comment: Just have your mouseClick call your printBinaryInt and then do that other stuff inside of that method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're forced to keep the method `printIntBinary` as it is (strange requirement since it prints directly to the console), then you can redirect the `System.out` stream temporarily to catch the results of that method:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    try{
        int mm = Integer.parseInt(binaryTextField.getText());

        // create temporary outputstream and set it to System.out
        final OutputStream originalOS = System.out;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
        System.setOut(ps);

        Recurs.printIntBinary(mm);
        binaryOutPut.append(os.toString());

        //reset System.out
        System.setOut(originalOS);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ertyui");
    }
}
```

This is an dirty workaround for that requirement.

If you link to avoid whitespaces (e.q. `\r` and `\n`) to be added to the textarea, then change `os.toString()` to `os.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "")`.

If you can change the method `printIntBinary` (except its return type), then you can do the following:

```
public static void printIntBinary(int x, JTextArea binaryOutPut) {
    if (x > 0) {
        printIntBinary(x / 2);
        binaryOutPut.append(String.valueOf(x % 2));
    }
}
```

If you like each number on its own line, then use `binaryOutPut.append(String.valueOf(x % 2) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));`.